# Google maps API in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to implement a functionality such that when a user enters an address in a text field and clicks on a button, that address should be copied into the destination field of Google maps and the user location should be set to  "My Location" (his current location).

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show route on Google Map, Just call an intent which passes current and destination latitude and longitude. You may also pass address in any case if don't know lat-long. After doing this, its Google Map's job to show location. You may also show street view.

In below code, there are three parameters : `current_lat, current_longi, dest_address`

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" 
+ "saddr="+ current_lat+","+current_longi + "&daddr="+dest_address ));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

startActivity(intent);
```

If you have current address and destination address, then you can write like this :

```
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" 
+ "saddr="+curr_address+ "&daddr="+dest_address ));
```

If you have current and destination latitude and longitude both then you can write like this :

```
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" 
+ "saddr="+ current_lat+","+current_longi + "&daddr="+ destt_lat+","+dest_longi  ));
```

When you call this intent, Google Map shows option whether to draw route by bus or by walk.

Answer (score 4):

You can open google map in following way:

```
String CURRENT_LOCATION = "current_location_latitude, current_location_longitude";
String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "address_from_your_text_view";

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ CURRENT_LOCATION +" daddr="+DESTINATION_LOCATION));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note: You should get device/user current location from LocationManager

Comment: It worked like a charm! Stack Overflow wont allow me to give you a plus 1. All I can say is thank you! :)

Comment: what if on back_press i don't want to show upper Maps option (with Map, Local etc...),
instead i need to show previous activity from where is has been called ??

Comment: If you are starting google map application from your application/activity through intent than you do not have control on back key press