# Google Maps API Android show Map of address in MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a SupportMapFragment

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
// ...
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I want to load the map for a particular address. The above code, I got at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map. 
I also saw this post [Google maps API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217831/google-maps-api-in-android) which talks about starting an activity. I don't want to do that but load it in the fragment. How do I do this? The APIs of Google Map (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) also don't have any appropriate method for loading map with specific address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this code,

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();

    if (map!=null){
      Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
          .title("Hamburg"));
      Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(KIEL)
          .title("Kiel")
          .snippet("Kiel is cool")
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
              .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    }

  }
```

Comment: I'm yet to check but this looks great! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Good job copying code from http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html and claiming credit! You should include links to code you reference, especially if it is just pasted from someone else's site.

Comment: @domji84 excuse me mate, may I know where did I claimed the credit? Did I say that the code was mine? And what is the problem with copying simple code like this? There is nothng special or tough in this code.I just found a simple method by searching over internet and provided it to OP.And finally, what is your problem ?

Comment: No problem. Just expressing that i think a link to the article would've been useful as it is a full maps v2 tutorial with information on adding markers as well as loads of other stuff.

Comment: @domji84 Then its Ok, thats the way you should put comments.Previous one wasn't fair :)

Answer (score 1):

use Geocoder to get the latitude and longitude for the address you want, then add a marker to the map with that latitude and longitude and set the camera to that point with the followinf statement

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(your latitude, your longitude), 11));
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: Thank you! Why is moving the camera necessary? Wouldn't this be slower than the above implementation? And an overhead of the moveCamera call?

Comment: when the map loads it will be in complete zoomed out state and i don't think it will focus to the placed marker position so using the camera is needed to focus on that position and also set the zoom level. well try without the move camera and see what happens, if it does not focus on the marker then use the camera. if it is focusing without camera then as you said using camera will be an overhead. let me know the result